# How can I let my stack overflow?

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart, matlab-figure, axes

I want to make a bar chart in Matlab, where one of the categories is "breaking through the roof" of the axes, over the y-axis limit, but I can't figure how to do this. When I change the upper limit to a lower value, the bar gets trucked.

What can I do?

Here is my data:

```
data =
   115   116    97    99   107   NaN   NaN   NaN
   111   118   101   114   102   108   111   119
```

I want the upper y-axis limit to be 600.

Here is what I tried:

```
bar(data,0.5,'stack')
ylim([0 600])
```

Here is a demonstration of the result:

[image: stack not overflow]

Comment: It was a bit difficult to understand what you want to do, before seeing the answer...

Comment: asking a stackoverlow question on stack overflow - you got to appreciate :D

Answer (score 12):

One simple option is to set the `clipping` property of the axes to `off`.

```
bar(data,'stack')
colormap('lines') % make it colorfull :)
bax = gca; % get axis handle
bax.Clipping = 'off';
bax.YLim(2) = 600; % set the upper limit
```

For a better result, you might want to also shrink the axes a little, so the bar will stay within the *figure*. Also, it's nicer without boxing the axes:

```
top = bax.YLim(2); % before you change the limit
bax.YLim(2) = 600; % set the upper limit
bax.Position(4) = bax.Position(4)*(bax.YLim(2)/top);
box off
```

the result:

[image: stack overflow]

Comment: Good to know! I don't remember having used that `clipping` property in the past